# How do I download a module which will let me do calculus on python using chrome os?

Tags: python, google-chrome, operating-system, integration

I'm a student working on an extra-curricular coding project and I have a Chromebook. I'm writing a Python programme which requires basic integration and I haven't been able to find any file that my chromebook will run which will let me do that. Does anyone know anything about that?

Thanks

JL

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like `sympy`. [Documentation for sympy's symbolic integrals is available here.](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html)

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
integrate(x**2 + x + 1, x)
```

should result in:

```
 3    2
x    x
-- + -- + x
3    2
```